# react - map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i need to uplift state from `SingleRowComponent` to `UpdateMessageBoxComponent`, in which i want to update the payload, which looks like this

```
[
  {
    "id":80,
    "title":"nowe",
    "content": [
      {
        "id":159,
        "checked":true,
        "content":"cwelowe"
      },
      {
        "id":160,
        "checked":false,
        "content":"guwno"
      },
      {
        "id":161,
        "checked":true,
        "content":"jeabne"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to achieve that by adding a `count` prop in `box.content.map()`

```
export default function UpdateMessageBoxComponent(props) {

    let [state, setState] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.id);
        RestService.getMessage(props.id).then(res => {
            setState(res.data)
        })
    }, [props])

    function handleRowState(i, data) {
        let copy = state
        copy[i] = data
        setState(copy)
    }
    
    return (
        
        state.map(box => (
            <div key={box.id}>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="title">Podaj nazwę</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={box.title} 
                onChange={e => setState([{ title: e.target.value, id: box.id, content: box.content }])}  />
            </div>
            <div className="additional">
                {
 -----------------  box.content.map((row, idx) => (   // THIS ONE HERE -------------------------
                        <SingleRowComponent key={row.id} count={idx} onRowChange={handleRowState} state={row}/>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            <div className="buttons">
                <button onClick={() => {console.log(state); RestService.updateMessage(box.id, state) }}>add</button>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    }}>finish</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        ))

    )
}
```

the issue is that an `box.content.map is not a function` error is thrown, when i don't use the `count` prop, everything works fine (except the fact that i don't actually update the state in the payload). i don't understand what's the issue here

```
function SingleRowComponent(props) {

    let payload;
    if (typeof props.state !== 'undefined')
        payload = {id:props.state.id, content:props.state.content, checked: props.state.checked}
    else
        payload = {content:'', checked: false}


    let [values, setValues] = useState(payload)
    useEffect(() => {
        props.onRowChange(props.count, values)
    })


    //uplifting state

    function changeCheckedHandler(e) {
        setValues({content:values.content,checked:e.target.checked})
        props.onRowChange(props.count, values)
    }

    
    function changeContentHandler(e) {
        setValues({content:e.target.value, checked:values.checked})
        props.onRowChange(props.count, values)
    }

    return (
        
            <div key={props.count}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="content">Podaj treść</label>
                    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10" value={values.content} onChange={changeContentHandler}></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="checked">checked</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checked" id="checked" checked={values.checked} onChange={changeCheckedHandler}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
    )
}
```

EDIT 1

[image: error]

i noticed that `box` after a few iterations becomes what `row` should be, hence the errors

Comment: The error indicates that what you have stored in state doesn't match what you presented at the top of your question when the code `box.content.map` is executed. You should ensure that every box has a content property with an array, even if the array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the `handleRowState` function inside `UpdateMessageBoxComponent` wrongfully assigning the inner `content` from single `row` as the entire state

not working

```
    function handleRowState(i, data) {
        let copy = state
        copy[i] = data
        setState(copy)
    }
```

solution

```
    function handleRowState(i, data) {
        let copy = state
        copy[0][i] = data  // <--------- here, the updated state is a 2-dimensional array
        setState(copy)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have your object wrapped in an Array, you need to call

```
box[0].content.map()
```

Comment: not the issue, ```box.content``` is already wrapped in ```state.map()```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Adding `{console.log(box)}` right after `<div className="additional">` might help you debug your issue.

Comment: I have to agree with OP here, [0] isn't relevant. box is an object in that location, not an array. (the error would be quite different if this weren't the case)